# Silverlight 4 and Outlook 2010 Out of Browser

Tags: silverlight, outlook, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, comautomationfactory

How/what is the best way to access a user outlook while out of browser in
Silverlight ?

I'm looking for sample code to start making queries on a user e-mail box
after the user installs a silverlight app.

I know this busts most if not all of the silverlight security sandboxes, but
installing elevates the app trust to that of the user.

dr K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/23/silverlight-4-grabbing-emails-from-the-outlook-inbox.aspx

Comment: +1 for right on the mark answer! also, someone with the creds should probably add two more flags of "outlook" and "ComAutomationFactory".

Comment: The on the mark, dead on, bulls-eye answer.